# Captions for tables included via pdfpages

Tags: captions, longtable, pdfpages

I have a large number of multipage longtables as independent pdfs. I am including these pdfs in my main document using the `pdfpages` package. My code for including the PDFs currently looks like this:

```
\section{Analysis}

We first present the data for group A (Table~\ref{tab:groupadata}).
{
\includepdf[pages={-},nup=1x1,templatesize={5.45in}{8.5in}, pagecommand={}, addtolist={1,table,Caption for the LOT,tab:groupadata}
]{directory/firstgroupdata.pdf}
}
```

I can get the captions for these tables to go into the List of Tables with the `addtolist= option` but how do I get the inserted PDF tables to have auto-captions like regular tables? I thought of hardcoding the caption into the longtable in the pdfs, but if I shuffle the position of the tables, it is a pain to go into the tex files and change the caption once more for each of the tables.

Any solutions or workarounds for adding captions to these external tables would be great. Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

use the `capt-of package` (only one line of code:-) then you can go

```
\captionof{table}{a table caption}
```

before or after each included table pdf.

Comment: Thank you for this solution! It works very well for portrait-oriented pages! So now my code looks like `{
\captionof{table}{Caption of table}
\label{tab:tablelabel} 
\includepdf[pages={-},nup=1x1,templatesize={5.45in}{8.5in},pagecommand={}]{directory/firsttable.pdf}
}` By including this: `pagecommand={\begin{center} Table~\ref{tab:tablelabel} \end{center}` I can get it to print this caption on top of the table. But what do I do for landscape oriented tables? It still puts the caption in portrait format.

Comment: you can probably use lscape package to rotate the pages including the inclusion and the caption

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I do not get that working. In the documentation of the caption package it is written that captionof **should only be used inside of environments**. But which one should I use? `\begin{figure} messes up everything

Comment: This is why we always ask people to supply a  [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) as it makes things easier to understand. In the landscape case you are probably already inside a landscape environment so you don't need another one.

Comment: @louiscypher I found that I had to rotate the pages in addition to putting them in a landscape environment. Something like this: `\begin{landscape}
{\includepdf[pages={-},angle=90, offset=8mm 0mm, pagecommand={\begin{center}\textbf{~\Cref{fig:label} caption goes here.}\end{center}}, addtolist={ 1, caption for TOC goes here, tab:label}]{path/to/example.pdf}
}
\end{landscape}`

Comment: Is it possible to get the caption on the same page where the last page of included pdfs end ? or on each of the pages ? Using captionof gives the figure caption but at the start of the next page after included pages. Tries adjusted the size but that approach doesnt work. Any solutions ?

Comment: @Anusha pdfs can't be reformatted so there isn't really any space to _add_ tex like captions if you are including a full page pdf, pdfpages package has some possibilities of changing the page head I think, but if you have tex source for the tables (as it seems was the case in the original question) it's much more flexible to include the tex source rather than already typeset pdf

Comment: I am using this for graphs. I found some clues using answers in this question https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/170113/caption-description-footnote-for-pdfpages?lq=1 but it is not giving the captions at the end of the page. Any additions to that approach ? Thanks.