# Caption / Description / Footnote for pdfpages

Tags: pdfpages

I am using the pdfpages package a lot for including either single pages or multiple pages in my document (measurement diagrams, several pages of external documentation, ...). I do not want to include those as pictures by `\includegraphics{}`, since that would resize them too much. The included pages usually have a format of being printed already anyway.

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\usepackage{pdfpages}

\begin{document}
% Include a single PDF page
\includepdf[
    frame,
    scale=0.90
]{pdfdocument.pdf}

% Include a pdf-document with several pages
\includepdf[
    pages=-,                
    nup=1x2,                
    frame,                  
    landscape,          
    delta=5mm 5mm,  
    scale=0.95,         
]{pdfdocument.pdf}

\end{document}
```

Any idea on how to set a description, caption or similar below or above the included document?

See this sketch for explanation.

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: You can use `pagecommand` and insert `header` or `footer` for each page. If for one page use `thispagestyle` macro. Do it for each pdf assuming that they are all one page documents.

Comment: Hello Harish, this was my first guess. Did not work for me well, so far, since the page layout needs to be changed constantly. I was already stopped by changing the layout accordingly with _scrlayer-scrpage_.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! The question is of high quality. You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Comment: relevant: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/57746/includepdf-as-a-figure and also http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/50781/captions-for-tables-included-via-pdfpages

Answer (score 6):

This answer attempts to do what you are asking via these steps:

1. Use `geometry` to set margins to accommodate the captions and page numbers you want.
2. Use `caption` package for its `\captionof` and `\captionof*` commands to set the captions.
3. Use `pdflscape` and wrap landscape pages in `landscape` environment to set captions in the proper orientation.
4. The example assumes one caption per included document.  To do this, `pdfpages` is patched to offer a `pagecommand*` option that will allow for a different command to be executed on the first page of included pages.  The way I have written things, `pagecommand*` is executed on the first page, and `pagecommand` is executed on second and subsequent pages (though this could be changed relatively easily if desired).  If you desire a different caption for different pages, it will be best to include the document 2 pages at a time (and in this case, the patches are not necessary).

#### Example Output:

The output that is given provides the page number on all pages (in portrait layout, ideal for printing).

[image: page1]

[image: page2]

[image: page3]

#### The Code

This code has been commented to give an idea of what was changed where.

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\usepackage{caption}  % Use for \captionof(*) command

% Set the page margins to accomodate space for captions and page numbers
\usepackage[left=0.9cm,right=0.9cm,bottom=1cm,footskip=1em,includefoot]{geometry}
% Use for 'landscape' environment to position landscape captions properly
\usepackage{pdflscape}

% Setup the new 'pagecommand*' option key-value
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\AM@pagecommandstar}{}
\define@key{pdfpages}{pagecommand*}{\def\AM@pagecommandstar{#1}}
\patchcmd{\AM@output}{\begingroup\AM@pagecommand\endgroup}
{\ifthenelse{\boolean{AM@firstpage}}{\begingroup\AM@pagecommandstar\endgroup}{\begingroup\AM@pagecommand\endgroup}}{}{} % Patch to use new option
\patchcmd{\AM@split@optionsii}{\equal{pagecommand}{\AM@temp}\or}
{\equal{pagecommand}{\AM@temp}\or\equal{pagecommand*}{\AM@temp}\or}{}{}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

% Include a single PDF page
\includepdf[
    frame,
    scale=0.90,
    % Use new 'pagecommand*' to set caption on the first page, include page #
   pagecommand*={\thispagestyle{plain}\null\vfill\captionof{figure}{This is the FIRST caption}}
]{pdfdocument.pdf}

% Include a pdf-document with several pages
\begin{landscape} % Be sure to wrap in 'landscape' environment
\includepdf[
    pages=-,                
    nup=1x2,                
    frame,                  
    landscape,          
    delta=5mm 5mm,  
    scale=0.90,
    % Set the caption on the first page of output
    pagecommand*={\thispagestyle{plain}\null\vfill\captionof{figure}{This is the SECOND caption}},
    % Set the [continued] caption on second and subsequent pages
    % Use '\captionof*{...} to avoid duplicate entries in listoffigures
    pagecommand={\thispagestyle{plain}\null\vfill\captionof*{figure}{\figurename~\thefigure: This is the SECOND caption (Continued)}}
]{pdfdocument.pdf}
\end{landscape}

\end{document}
```

Comment: This was very helpful for adapting to another style!

Comment: Hello !! I would like to use the same functionality !! however I need the caption to be on top of the pdf doc ( 3 pages long table) and I want it to repeat itself on each page!! how is this possible.

Answer (score 0):

Another solution using the `\addtolist` functionality of pdfpages, and changing the layout with `geometry`.

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{a4paper}

\usepackage[]{scrlayer-scrpage}

% Fußzeile
\ofoot[\pagemark]{\pagemark}
\cfoot[]{Section}
\ifoot[]{Document number}
\pagestyle{scrheadings}

\newcommand{\pdfportrait}[2]{
\newgeometry{bottom=0.5cm,includefoot}
\cfoot[#1]{}
\includepdf[
    frame,
    scale=0.90,
    addtolist={1,figure,#1,#1},
    pagecommand={\thispagestyle{plain}}
]{#2}
\restoregeometry
}

\newcommand{\pdfbooklet}[2]{
\newgeometry{bottom=0.5cm,includefoot}
\cfoot[#1]{}
\includepdf[
    pages=-,                
    nup=1x2,                
    frame,                  
    landscape,          
    delta=5mm 5mm,  
    scale=0.90,
    addtolist={1,figure,#1,#1},
    pagecommand={\thispagestyle{plain}}
]{#2}
\restoregeometry
}

\begin{document}

\listoffigures

\lipsum

% Include a single PDF page
\pdfportrait{Single page portrait oriented}{pdfdocument.pdf}

\lipsum

% Include a pdf-document with several pages
\pdfbooklet{Multiple pages - 2 per page}{pdfdocument.pdf}

\lipsum

\end{document}
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]