Split a figure automatically
I have a long table as a PDF file about two or three pages. Is there a way to automatically have this PDF continuously shown on pages? I want also to have a caption for that. I prefer to use include figure instead of include pdf unless you have a better suggestion to make it nicer. It might be very simple. I want to show this pdf file continuously with a nice caption at the end. What I do is:
\begin{figure}
        \centering
        \includegraphics{a.pdf}
        \caption{Caption}
        \label{fig:enter-label}
 \end{figure}

But it only prints on the first page where it appears.

You've set the longtable tag -- Does this mean that you've set up the table as a longtable envrironment? If so, there should be automatic page breaking. If not, please do provide more specific and actionable information as to what you've done so far.

@Mico Actually no, I do not want to use longtable. I already know we can split this pdf file and use it as subfigures, but what I am looking for is to automatically have this pdf file as float, but continuous. I mean wherever it starts, it should be continuous in a couple of pages. It might be very simple. I want to show this pdf file continuously with a nice caption at the end.

No, there's no way to do this. The included pdf is just a box so it will just produce an overfull \vbox. If you really want to do it this way, you need to split it up and insert the pieces separately. Since the pieces also won't split, you should ideally do this after all the other text in your document is finalized.

@DavidCarlisle No, that brings a lot of problems.

@AlanMunn I see. That would be so difficult as I have a lot of figures. So, I should write it in longtable.

How was the original PDF generated? If the data is in some sort of readable form (CSV, R dataframe etc) you should be able to generate the table relatively easily.

Maybe https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/50781/captions-for-tables-included-via-pdfpages is what you are looking for?

@DavidCarlisle As I understand the OP the PDF is not an image per se, but a table that has been printed as a PDF from some other source.

oh, you only want to include each page not crop so that;s easier instead of the viewport key I showed in the linked answer, use \includegraphics[page=1]{file.pdf} ... \includegraphics[page=2]{file.pdf} ...

@AlanMunn yes as I read now also OP just wants to split by pages rather than split a long pdf page, so that's easier as \includegraphics supports that directly:-)

It might be helpful to add to your original question some drawn example of what you have and what you want. I currently don't really understand whether the original is a table or a PDF and whether this PDF has one of more pages and what part of that you want to put where in your document.

"automatic" is a bit tricky as typically you need to trim parts of the original, at least losing the page numbers.
Here I include a two page table from the longtable package into another document. Scale it slightly so it will fit while adding new page numbers and caption, and trim out the original caption and page head/foot, and some text from a following section.
The longtable manual looks like:

And the first table included into another document, and re-captioned at the end:

\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}

This is a new main document

\begin{figure}[p]
  \centering
   % /usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/doc/latex/tools/longtable.pdf
   \fbox{\includegraphics[page=2,scale=0.9,trim=4cm 4cm 4cm 5cm,clip]{longtable.pdf}}
\end{figure}
\begin{figure}[p]
  \centering
   % /usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/doc/latex/tools/longtable.pdf
  \fbox{\includegraphics[page=3,scale=0.9,trim=4cm 10cm 4cm 5cm,clip]{longtable.pdf}}
  \caption{more normal to caption multi-page tables at the start
           so people know what they are about before reading them}
\end{figure}


\clearpage

and more text
\end{document}

